# Traveling across an arc?

Tags: geometry

So, I have an arc that's part of a circle that I must "travel across".

The circle has a radius of $15$ - a circumference of $94.248$ (rounding). The arc length in question is equal to $15.708$.

Now, normally, you could sort of walk along the arc, turning with it. But, if I could only travel straight, I need to know how I would get from one part of the arc to $15.708$ units later in the arc of the circle (only being able to travel straight, or make $90$ degree turns).

Comment: **[Very related.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12906)**

Answer (score 1):

For a thousand years, the only extensive trigonometric table was about precisely this question: see [Ptolemy's table of chords](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy%27s_table_of_chords).

If the central angle is $\theta$ and the diameter is $d$, then the length of the chord is $d\sin(\theta/2)$.

Observe that $\dfrac{15.708}{94.248}=\dfrac 16$, so the central angle is $60^\circ$.  For a $60^\circ$ angle, the length of the chord is exactly the radius.

Answer (score 0):

Pictures should be drawn to match my verbal descriptions.

The situation is particularly simple with your numbers.  The circumference $c$ of your circle is $(2\pi)(15)$.  If you calculate $\frac{15.708}{c}$, you will get about $0.1666671$.  With your slightly rounded circumference, the ratio is $0.1666667$.  To the limit of accuracy of our data, the arc is therefore one-sixth of the full circumference.

So if $O$ is the centre of the circle, $A$ the start point of your travels, and $B$ the end point, then $\triangle OAB$ is equilateral.  Thus if you can draw the line joining $A$ to the center of the circle, you want $\angle BAO$ to be $60^\circ$.  Such an angle is easy to draw with straightedge and compass.

Once $AB$ has been drawn, you can go directly from $A$ to $B$, and your path will be the shortest possible.

A less efficient thing to do is to travel from $A$ along the line $AO$, until you have walked a distance of $7.5$ (half the radius).  Then you turn $90^\circ$, and walk steadily towards the circle. The right bisector of $OA$  will meet the circle at the right points.